# Clear all cells which do not have a color

Tags: excel, vba

I have a big table (100 columns * 1000 rows) and certain cells in this table are filled with different colors (red, yellow, blue, orange and other colors). I want to clear all selected cells that have no colors. I wrote a simple macro that will be good for a small table, but for a large table, the computational power drops and if several colored cells are selected in the same range, then the cells are not cleared. How can I reduce the cleaning time of the table and fix the error when the specified area has different colors?

```
Sub ClearData()
For Each cell in Selection
If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
cell.ClearContents
End If
Next cell
MsgBox "Done!"
End Subs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub ClearData()

    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim URng As Range

    For Each Cell In Selection
        If Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then GoSub UnionRange
    Next

    If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.ClearContents: MsgBox "Done!"

Exit Sub

UnionRange:

    If Not URng Is Nothing Then
        Set URng = Union(URng, Cell)
    Else
        Set URng = Cell
    End If
    Return

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub ClearData()
Dim c As Range, r As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each c In .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            If c.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
                If r Is Nothing Then Set r = c Else Set r = Union(r, c)
            End If
        Next c

        If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Cells.Clear
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Done...", 64
End Sub
```